# Where does makecert store the private key if -sv is not specified?

Tags: certificate

Let say I run this command:

```
makecert testcert.cer
```

Is a private key created? If so, where is it automatically stored in the system even though I did not tell makecert to install this certificate in any certificate store?

Answer (score 4):

The way you run the commnand does not create any private key.
To generate a certificate with private key, you have to use the option -pe.
But this is not suficient. Private key will only be created if your certificate destination is a store. So you'll have to use the command like this:

makecert -pe -ss My testcert.cer

"my" corresponds to the "personal" store.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Also please note that makecert.exe doesn't tell you that it isn't going to embed private key into certificate. It just creates it on disk without private key. So you can use `-pe -ss My` options to create in into the storage and then export it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the private key is stored in the file itself.  From the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.80).aspx it states...

Caution
You should use a certificate store to securely store your certificates. The .snk files used by this tool store private keys in an unprotected manner. When you create or import a .snk file, you should be careful to secure it during use and remove it when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is not created because I HasPrivateKey of X509Certificate2 is set to false when I load the certificate in .NET.